# How to add content of div with certain class to other page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to display one part of a web page on another page. This specific div has a class name, but not an id. The parent div does have an id, and more than one child div.

I tried using an [iframe](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe), but I can only manage to get the whole page displayed. When I tried to use jQuery's [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method nothing showed. How can I use an iframe to only display one div?

And if I cannot use an iframe to do so, is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method...

Try

```
<div id="mycontainer"></div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#mycontainer').load('/mypageurl.xxx .myclass')
})
```

It will load the contents of element with class `myclass` in the page with url `mypageurl.xxx` to an element with id `mycontainer` in the current page

Comment: Ah thanks, but I just changed the question a bit to explain that I tried the load method, and that it did not work. The pages are on the same intranet, but not on the same domain. The specific div also used a lot of JavaScript.

Comment: @user2609980 can you enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) in the `/mypageurl.xxx` site - also be aware of IE < 9 does not support it

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid we're still using IE8 there, but they're slowly going to IE10 so I will ask the webmaster if he can enable it.

Comment: Is it not possible to load only a class from an iframe? Do note that the the div in the other page is created with JavaScript